# What is so wrong with extract()?

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I was recently reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233030/worst-php-practice-found-in-your-experience/233746), on some of the worst PHP practices.
In the second answer there is a mini discussion on the use of `extract()`, and im just wondering what all the huff is about.

I personally use it to chop up a given array such as `$_GET` or `$_POST` where I then sanitize the variables later, as they have been conveniently named for me.

Is this bad practice? What is the risk here? What are your thoughts on the use of `extract()`?

Comment: Your own example of using it on $_GET or $_POST is probably WHY people are against it. The PHP developers removed `register_globals` because it causes security problems and `extract()`ing them emulates this deprecated/removed behavior. (Good to know if you have some old codebase you can't be bothered to actually upgrade.)

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306498/php-is-there-a-safe-way-to-extract-post#answer-5306543

And for more details to know which extracting rules best for you check this: https://phptutors.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/php-extract-function-example/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I find that it is only bad practice in that it can lead to a number of variables which future maintainers (or yourself in a few weeks) have no idea where they're coming from. Consider this scenario:

```
extract($someArray); // could be $_POST or anything

/* snip a dozen or more lines */

echo $someVariable;
```

Where did `$someVariable` come from? How can anyone tell?

I don't see the problem in accessing the variables from within the array they started in, so you'd really need to present a good case *for* using `extract()` for me to think it's worth it. If you're really concerned about typing out some extra characters then just do this:

```
$a = $someLongNameOfTheVariableArrayIDidntWantToType;

$a['myVariable'];
```

I think the comments here on the security aspects of it are overblown somewhat. The function can take a second parameter that actually gives you fairly good control over the newly created variables, including not overwriting any existing variables (`EXTR_SKIP`), ONLY overwriting existing variables (so you can create a whitelist) (`EXTR_IF_EXISTS`), or adding prefixes to the variables (`EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`).

Comment: extract() is pretty useful when you're using unpack().

Comment: `extract` can also be really useful when parsing a CSV or Excel file, where you know what each column should contain and each line/row is read in as an array of values. However, I generally avoid using it for the reasons @nickf already described. In short: with great power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 44):

Come on now. People blame the tool instead of the user.

That's like talking against `unlink()` because you can delete files with it. `extract()` is a function like any other, use it wisely and responsibly. But don't claim it's bad per se, that's just ignorant.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes the only way to use something wisely is not use it.

Comment: @DanLugg, and sometimes the only way to use the advice *"sometimes the only way to use something wisely is not use it"* wisely is to not use it.

Comment: @Pacerier I C WUT U DID THAR. But seriously, `extract()` and [varvars](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (as they are related) are... tricky. They introduce hard-to-track variables, somewhat magically, into your program. If you're using them, why not just use an associative array? It's (IMO) far cleaner; you have a single point-of-entry, rather than treating the local scope as one.

Comment: @DanLugg, Because sometimes/manytimes "your program" is not fully made up of "your code". So now there's a .php file by someone else that you forced to include and it requires you to set variables $a $b $c to $zz before including it. **And the values from those variables will come from another source**. Are you going to write a hundred lines of variable declarations or are you going to extract an array? It's much cleaner to create a new scope and extract all the variables there, After all, there's no way those extracted vars could leak out of that scope created specifically for it.

Comment: @Pacerier Fair enough. But then again, I'd call to question the quality of code that depends on things like `$a` through `$zz`. I mean, legacy gonna legacy but I'd rather fix the "mess" in the most reasonable way possible and be done with it (for instance, wrapping the "capturing" of said values into some container, and exposing them through a sensible API). Magically available variables is just bad voodoo, whether the product of you or someone else. For context, I feel similarly about the superglobals.

Comment: @DanLugg, Trying to "fix" legacy code this way is **extremely dangerous** especially so when they are not written by you. Indeed, my solution above is the cleanest way to "fix" legacy code. All we need is an extra facet pattern **on top** of that function which uses `extract`. Not only cleanest, but cheapest (e.g. a $2000/month breaks down to $10/hour), and failproof-est. Is there even an alternative solution that is cleaner **or** cheaper **or** more failproof then the solution I mentioned above?

Answer (score 18):

the risk is: don't trust data from users, and extracting into the current symbol table means, your variables could be overwritten by something the user provides.

```
<?php
    $systemCall = 'ls -lh';
    $i = 0;

    extract($_GET);

    system($systemCall);

    do {
        print_r($data[$i];
        $i++;
    } while ($i != 3);

?>
```

(a nonsensical example)

but now a malicious user who guesses or knows the code calls:

```
yourscript.php?i=10&systemCall=rm%20-rf
```

instead of

```
yourscript.php?data[]=a&data[]=b&data[]=c
```

now, $systemCall and $i are overwritten, resulting in your script deleting your data first and hanging then.

Comment: you can use EXTR_SKIP to avoid this situation though.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with it. Otherwise it wouldnt be implemented. Many (MVC) frameworks use it when you pass (assign) variables to Views. You just need to use it carefully. Sanitize those arrays before passing it to extract() and make sure it does not override your variables. Dont forget that this function also accepts a few more arguments!
Using the second and third arguments you can control the behavior if collision occurs. You can override, skip or add prefix.
http://www.php.net/extract

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with it. Otherwise it wouldnt be implemented."..........[`goto`](http://us1.php.net/goto), [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 6):

If not used carefully it can confuse the heck out of others you work with consider:

```
<?php

    $array = array('huh' => 'var_dump', 'whatThe' => 'It\'s tricky!', 'iDontGetIt' => 'This Extract Function');
    extract($array);
    $huh($whatThe, $iDontGetIt);


?>
```

Yields:

```
string(12) "It's tricky!"
string(21) "This Extract Function"
```

Would be useful to use in an obfuscation. But I can't get over the "Where did that var come from?" problem that I run into.

Answer (score 6):

People get all up-in-arms about extract because it has the *potential* to be misused. Doing something like extract($_POST) is not a good idea in any case, even if you know what you are doing. However, it does have it's uses when you are doing things like exposing variables to a view template or something similar. Basically, only use it when you are very certain that you have a good reason for doing so, and understand how to use the extract type parameter if you get the idea of passing something crazy like $_POST to it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the reason a lot of people don't recommend using it is that extracting `$_GET` and `$_POST` (even `$_REQUEST`) superglobals registers variables in the global namespace with the same name as each key within those arrays, which is basically emulating REGISTER_GLOBALS = 1.

Answer (score 4):

If you extract in a function, the variables will only be available in that scope. This is often used in views. Simple example:

```
//View.php
class View {
    function render($filename = null) {
        if ($filename !== null) {
            $this->filename = $filename;
        }
        unset($filename);
        extract($this->variables);
        ob_start();
        $this->returned = include($this->dir . $this->filename);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

//test.php
$view = new View;
$view->filename = 'test.phtml';
$view->dir = './';
$view->variables = array('test' => 'tset');
echo $view->render('test.phtml');
var_dump($view->returned);

//test.phtml
<p><?php echo $test; ?></p>
```

With some alternative directories, checks to see if the file exists and defined variables and methods - you've pretty much replicated Zend_View.

You can also add *$this->outVariables = get_defined_vars();* after the include to run code with specific variabels and get the result of these for use with old php code.

Answer (score 3):

I'll let the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) do the talking for me.

Background: `extract($_REQUEST)` is the same as setting `register_globals = On` in php.ini

Comment: Dont extract superglobals and you will be fine. Extract is a powerfull tool used correctly.

Comment: @OIS: Provided you pass arguments for its optional parameters, I'll agree.  It still seems like a better idea to access what you want directly, though.

Answer (score 2):

Never extract($_GET) in a global scope. Other than that, it has its uses, like calling a function that could (potentially) have lots of optional arguments.

This should look vaguely familiar to WordPress developers:

```
function widget (Array $args = NULL)
{
    extract($args);

    if($before_widget) echo $before_widget;

    // do the widget stuff

    if($after_widget) echo $after_widget;
}

widget(array(
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract is safe as long as you use it in a safe manner. What you want to do is filter the array's keys to only the ones you intend to use and maybe check that all those keys exist if your scenario requires their existence.

```
#Extract only the specified keys.
$extract=array_intersect_key(
    get_data()
    ,$keys=array_flip(['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5'])
);

#Make sure all the keys exist.
if ($missing=array_keys(array_diff_key($keys,$extract))) {
    throw new Exception('Missing variables: '.implode(', ',$missing));
}

#Everything is good to go, you may proceed.
extract($extract);
```

or

```
#If you don't care to check that all keys exist, you could just do this.
extract(array_intersect_key(
    get_data()
    ,array_flip(['key1','key2','key3','key4','key5'])
));
```

Answer (score 1):

The risk is the same as with register_globals. You enable the attacker to set variables in your script, simply by tampering with the request.

Comment: Dont extract superglobals and you will be fine. Extract is a powerfull tool used correctly.

Comment: "Don't poke yourself in the eye with a sharp stick and you will be fine. A sharp stick is a powerful tool when used correctly." -- I was referring to the use of extract($_POST) at script level, which is the clear equivalent of poking yourself in the eye with a sharp stick.

Comment: Extract has a bad rep for allowing clueless ppl to do stupid things, but it allows smart people to do some nice things. You reply is lacking in information. You dont risk the same as register_globals or allowing attackers to set variables just by using extract. You do so by using extract unwisely and cluelessly.

Answer (score 1):

As someone noted in a different thread, [here is a safer way to use extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#59152), by only allowing it to extract variables you specify, instead of everything the array contains.

This serves a dual purpose of documenting what variables are coming out of it so tracking back a variable wont be so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Every method usage can lead to some conditions where it can be a point of failure for application. 
I personally feel that extract() should not be used for user input(that is not predictable) and for data that is not sanitized.

Even CodeIgniter core code uses extract, so there must be no harm in using the method if data is sanitized and handled well.

I have used extract in CodeIgniter models with the EXTR_IF_EXISTS switch and limiting the number of variables, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `extract()` is not safe if you are working with user data (like results of requests), so it is better to use this function with the flags `EXTR_IF_EXISTS` and `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`.

If you use it right, it safe to use

Answer (score 0):

To just expound a little on previous answers... There's nothing wrong with extract() so long as you filter the input correctly (as other's have stated); otherwise you can end up with huge security issues like this:

```
<?php

// http://foobar.doo?isLoggedIn=1

$isLoggedIn = (new AdminLogin())->isLoggedIn(); // Let's assume this returns FALSE

extract($_GET);

if ($isLoggedIn) {
    echo "Okay, Houston, we've had a problem here.";
} else {
    echo "This is Houston. Say again, please.";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One additional good reason to no longer use extract() is that there is a momentum in PHP to use [HHVM](http://hhvm.com/) which is claiming to make PHP about 10x faster. Facebook (who made it) is using it, Wikipedia is on it, and WordPress is rumored to to be looking at it.

[HHVM doesn't allow extract()](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/rarentry.extract.php)

It's still kind of alpha, so it's not the largest concern

Comment: Wrong link, here it is and it is implemented: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.extract.php