# Mysql results as PHP named variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql called **site_settings** that looks like this

[Table in PHPMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zkkX.png)

I am trying to store all of my website settings in mysql and want to pull them into PHP as variables.

I want to pull all values from the **variable_name** column as the $variable names in PHP and have their values set to whats in the **variable_type** column.

**$site_name** = Vexed

**$registration_enabled** = False

here is my code:

```
$sql = connect($database_address, $database_username, $database_password, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM site_settings";
$result = $sql->query($query);
//$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $$row['variable_name'] = $row["variable_type"];
}

$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

the last two lines i am using to see if the variable have been created but i cant get it to work. the best result i have got so far is

```
    [Array] => Array
        (
            [variable_name] => Vexed
        )
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: I'd recommend against this, as you can clobber existing variables pretty easily. You'll have to make sure you never create a setting that's named the same as any in-use variable. You're better off reading them into a `$config` array or an instance of a `stdClass` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is happening is that when you call `$$arr['variable_name']` it's actually doing `$$arr` first (which evaluates to $Array after the string conversion), and then trying to assign into assign the ['variable_name'] key into $Array.

I would expect this minor modification to work:

```php
$sql = connect($database_address, $database_username, $database_password, $database);

$query = "SELECT * FROM site_settings";
$result = $sql->query($query);
//$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $name = $row['variable_name'];
  $$name = $row["variable_type"];
}

$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

Edit: I'll also echo, that it's a little bit weird to dynamically create variables in this way and it will make your code hard to follow.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, agreed it a little weird, i am creating a site where i can check and monitor different web apps, to monitor everything in one site i need to store a lot of values, my Mysql skills are much sharper than my php, hence going the route i have, is there a better way to store the values? i'm trying to create the site as open as possible so that i can share with others, or use the base of the site on different projects.

Comment: I'd probably shove everything into a look up dictionary/array like this:

$settings = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $settings[$row['variable_name']] = $row['variable_value'];
}

Then later on in the code you can access everything through $variables array.

e.g. $settings['site_name'] = Vexed, $settings['registration_enabled'] = true, etc.

Comment: where would you write this data though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "write" the data? Long-term persistent storage would still be in the database and all the settings in short-term memory would be accessed through the $settings dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, yeah i meant long term persistent storage, so storing in a database is fine but calling them into php the way i do is the concern, is there somewhere i could find some examples on the recommended way to store site values?

Comment: What you're doing for persistent storage is pretty standard. We do that on a few projects. If you're curious, I'd recommend looking up how Wordpress and Drupal configure their databases.

Comment: Ok, thats again for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to duplicate is [PHP's extract() builtin function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

It's generally considered a bad practice, because it will make your code harder for readers to understand or debug.

- [What is so wrong with extract()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract)
- [How to demonstrate an exploit of extract($_POST)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837789/how-to-demonstrate-an-exploit-of-extract-post)
- https://dzone.com/articles/php-bad-practice-use-extract
- https://blog.josephscott.org/2009/02/05/i-dont-like-phps-extract-function/