# PHP: is there a safe way to extract($_POST)

Tags: php

Is there a safe way to auto assign the keys in a posted array? Below are two examples of wrong ways...

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
     $$key = $value;
}
```

or

```
extract($_POST)
```

Is there a better way, or is it best to code:

```
$foo = $_POST('foo');
$bar = $_POST('bar');
....
```

for all 50 inputs on my form?

(the posted info will be inserted into a database).

Comment: It is best to refer to them with `$_POST['variablename']`.

Comment: What do you want to do with them afterwards, thats the question.

Comment: I know you're against extract (wisely) but what about making use of the prefix (and overwriting) options? See http://php.net/extract for more details. I'd think that should leave you safe enough?

Comment: Both of your versions are simply trying to recreate the utterly moronic PHP "register_globals". The parents of the original PHP developer(s) responsible for that should've been burned at the stake to prevent it ever having been conceived of.

Comment: @Alistair: Depends on the prefixed used, can still get accidental/tainted overrides, if your prefix matches the start of any variables.

Comment: @AbiusX: usually, I will be inserting them into a mySql database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One more cautious way of extracting all input fields at once is:

```
extract( $_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE, "form_" );
```

This way all your input variables will be called `$form_foo` and `$form_bar` at least. Avoid doing that in the global scope - not because global is evil, but because nobody ever cleans up there.

However, since mostly you do that in a localized scope, you can as well apply htmlentities if for example you need all fields just for output:

```
extract(array_map("htmlspecialchars", $_POST), EXTR_OVERWRITE, "form_");
```

Comment: haha just what i was writing now. +1 anyway i used it only on eg. $_POST['new_entry']

Comment: is there a potential for a security threat with this method... is it bulletproof?

Comment: @superUntitled: As I said on the comments to the question: "Depends on the prefixed used, can still get accidental/tainted overrides, if your prefix matches the start of any variables."

Comment: Variables itself are never a security threat. It depends on how you use them. Having them in an array or under localized names makes no difference. Unless of course you use monster functions with lots of responsibilities and behaviour, where such `$form_xyz` certainly contribute to muddling the application flow.

Answer (score 9):

There is not a single reason to do it.
To handle user inputs an array is 100 times better than separate variables

Comment: @superUntitled I'd rather assign it to another array in case of printing it back into form

Comment: I do not think I am quite getting it... so you would recommend something like: `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
$vars[$key] = $value;
}`

Comment: @superUntitled no, just `$FORM = array_map('htmlspecialchars',$_POST);`

Comment: If you're going to put the data into a database, don't blanket HTML-escape it. Only do that if you're going to output it to HTML.

Comment: @deceze there was another comment, dunno where it gone. The OP was going to print it out, to show form back in case of errors I suppose

Answer (score 3):

I like an approach where you let dynamic getters and setters in a class do all the work for you. Here's how I would code it.

**First,** create a bass class to hold data:

```
class FormParameterHandler {
  protected $parameters;
  public function __construct($associative_array) {
    $this->parameters = array();
    foreach($associative_array as $key => $value) {
      $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    $value = null;
    if(method_exists($this, "get_$key")) {
      $value = $this->{"get_$key"}();
    } else {
      $value = $this->parameters[$key];
    }
    return $value;
  }
  public function __set($key, $value) {
    if(method_exists($this, "set_$key")) {
      $this->{"set_$key"}($value);
    } else {
      $this->parameters[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

**Next,** create a specific class to use for some specific form where there is something special to validate. Use your freedom as a programmer here to implement it any way you want to. And remember, since we're using reflection to look for setter methods, we can write specific setter methods for known problem areas, like e.g. to check for equal passwords in a "register user" form:

```
class RegisterFormParameterHandler extends FormParameterHandler {
  private $passwords_are_equal = null;
  public function __construct($register_form_parameters) {
    parent::__construct($register_form_parameters);
  }
  public function has_equal_passwords() {
    return $this->passwords_are_equal;
  }
  public function set_password($password) {
    $this->parameters['password'] = $password;
    $this->compare_passwords();
  }
  public function set_password_repeat($password_repeat) {
    $this->parameters['password_repeat'] = $password_repeat;
    $this->compare_passwords();
  }
  private function compare_passwords() {
    if(isset($this->parameters['password']) && isset($this->parameters['password_repeat'])) {
      $this->passwords_are_equal = ($this->parameters['password'] === $this->parameters['password_repeat']);
    }
  }
}
```

**Finally,** use the derived class in a "register user" flow, to easily find out if the two entered passwords match:

```
$registerFormParameterHandler = new RegisterFormParameterHandler($_POST);
if($registerFormParameterHandler->has_equal_passwords()) {
  print "are equal";
  //register user
} else {
  print "are not equal";
}
```

You can test this by creating an HTML form that has one input field with the name "password", and another input field with the name "password_repeat".

To access any of the form data, use your form data object variable name, followed by the access operator "dash larger than" -> , followed by the name of the parameter. In the example above, if there was an input field named "user_name", it would be accessed through a call to

```
$registerFormParameterHandler->user_name
```

Rr, if you have defined the name of the field you want to get in some other variable, use reflection:

```
$registerFormParameterHandler->{$settings['form_data_user_name']}
```

Have fun! :)

Comment: +1 for effort. That's certainly overengineering in many cases. Getter/setter methods are unfavorable, but I like that you avoid CamelCase for method names, and it's a useable approach to place verifying  business logic where it belongs.

Comment: thanks! :) delegating responsibilities to the most suitable place was my intention ^^ but why are getter/setter methods unfavorable? they play such an important role in this scenario. it's thanks to them that it's possible to have safe guarding methods for a select few properties, and basic unguarded behavior for the rest. also, white listing is possible, although i didn't implement it in this example. would white listing functionality make it better in your opinion?

Comment: I like the theory and general idea of your answer, but I feel that in regards to the question of "safety" when extracting array elements from the $_POST superglobal, you have not moved the ball forward. In the `FormParameterHandler` class, your constructor could be unsafe because it makes an assumption about the $_POST elements (that they are fit to be made properties).

Answer (score 2):

While it is best to refer to them with `$_POST['variablename']`, it is possible to expand only the variables you are expecting.

```
$expected = array('name', 'telephone', /* etc */);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (!in_array($key, $expected)) {
    continue;
  }
  ${$key} = $value;
}
```

Or, I prefer this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'name':
    case 'telephone':
    /* etc. */
      ${$key} = $value;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A ***safe*** way to extract variables into the local scope is **not to**. You're injecting variables into your local scope, which is a problem however you do it. Even if you limit the variables to only a few select ones that won't clash with other variable names in the scope *now*, if you start adding elements to your form you may be in trouble later.

Arrays are specifically for holding an unlimited amount of named values without crowding the variable namespace. Use them! You may have to type a little more, but that's par for the course.

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip deceze.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the computer, language, and security knowledge of the programmer. The opening sequence of processing $_POST is kind of like the opening move in a game of chess. Many use `foreach` loops without realizing that `foreach` will make a copy of the contents of $_POST the way you have it used (Programming PHP: Chapter 5, p.128-129). Wouldn't it be funny if you caused a buffer overflow simply by using `foreach`!

One commenter implied that everything should just be worked with inside of the `$_POST` superglobal. There are some merits to this... However, forgetting cache memory for a moment, access to array values is slower than direct access to a variable.

Since you have fifty (50) controls to validate (with potentially large contents), I might not want to take that array access performance hit more than 50 times (the original access hits). Moreover, if you are concerned about writing secure input validation routines, keeping your *dirty* laundry (non-validated input) separate from your *clean* (validated input) laundry is a good idea. That said, you may need a *clean* array anyway (hence the $_POST advocate's response), but at least you are reducing risk in the process by keeping the *hopefully good* separate from the *potentially bad*.

Is there a safe way to auto assign the keys in a posted array?

I might start like this:

Function library for this example.

---

```
function all_controls_submitted($controls) {
  $postKeys = array_keys($_POST);
  foreach($controls as $key) {
    if(! array_key_exists($key, $postKeys)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function all_controls_set($controls) {
  foreach($controls as $key) {
    if(! isset($_POST[$key])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

```
if(is_array($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/contact.php') {
  $newForm = true;
} elseif (is_array($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/contact.php') {
  $newForm = false;
  $controlNames = array('firstName', 'lastName', 'e-mail', 'company', 'subject', 'message', 'captcha');
  define('NUM_CONTROLS_EXPECTED', count($controlNames)); //Seven (7)
  if(is_array($_POST) && count($_POST) === NUM_CONTROLS_EXPECTED && all_controls_submitted($controlNames) && all_controls_set($controlNames)) {
    //Begin input validation
  }
} else {
  header('location: http://www.nsa.gov');
}
```

---

Notice that I prep things with the `$controlNames` array, therefore I do not have to ask `$_POST` for the keys. After all, I should know them! :-) The two user-defined functions, `all_controls_submitted()` and `all_controls_set()` are two fundamental questions that should be asked before trying to use any values in `$_POST` (I say, anyway). Admittedly, I do use `$_POST` in `all_controls_submitted()`, but only to obtain the names of the controls submitted, not the values.

```
$postKeys = array_keys($_POST);
```

However, who is to say that the control names themselves could not be poisonous and in need of input validation?!! Same goes for values in $_SERVER. See, a chess game.

Is there a safe way to auto assign the keys in a posted array? I cannot tell you for certain, but perhaps something like the code above could help? You'd have the keys, at least.

Programming PHP: Chapter 5, p.125

Answer (score 0):

Try this inbuilt method/function **filter_input**

Reference URL: [php.net function filter input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: The question is safe-way-to-extract-post, You will come to know whether my answer is correct or not if you had read my Reference URL document.