# Is it possible to apply a filter (say a trim) and remove the _POST to any POST input?

Tags: php

Is it possible to build a function like

```
filterAllPost(ANY-POST-VARIABLE-TOTHIS PAGE, filterFunction);

filterFunction($argument){

// apply filter, eg. trim()

}
```

so for example if I submit a form with `$id`
i automatically import the variable, trim, and return the variable as `$id` instead of `$_POST['id']`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306498/php-is-there-a-safe-way-to-extract-post

Answer (score 1):

I think `array_map()` is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
<?php
function filter($n)
{
    return(trim($n));
}

$post = array_map("filter", $_POST);
print_r($post);
?>
```

Don't know if you can overwrite $_POST var...

Comment: You can simplify it with `$post = array_map("trim", $_POST);`.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think there might be an issue if the $_POST contains arrays as elements.

Comment: @David: True. `array_walk_recursive()` to the rescue! :-)