# Can I split a $_session array into string variables in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables, key-value

I've been able to collect variables from user input on each page but I'm trying to figure out whether I can turn `$_SESSION['post'][$key]=$value;` into something like this:

```
$name = $_SESSION[$name];
$cuisine = $_POST['cuisine'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$price = $_['price'];
```

Each variable here is what the user inputs on each page. Am I able to split `$_SESSION` array?

I've been searching for days on how to do this but this is what I've got so far..

```
//this can be found on all the pages to retrieve the user input

<?php
session_start();
//retrieve form data and store as an array as key/value
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $_SESSION['post'][$key]=$value;
}
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

So I have the array from the above code:
Array ( [post] => Array ( [name] => Michael [cuisine] => Asian [location] => CBD [price] => $ ) )

Logic: start session

Page 1 - Question 1: "user input"

Page 2 - Question 2: "user input"

Page 3 - Question 3: "user input"

Final page = compare user input with mysql query array

Sorry about any confusion, its my first post.

Comment: Wouldn't `foreach ( $_SESSION['post'] AS $name=>$value)...` be better to access the values.

Answer (score 1):

> [**extract()**](https://www.php.net/extract) : Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

```
$a = ['name' => 'A', 
    'cuisine'    => 'B',
    'location'   => 'C',
    'price'      => 12.3
];
extract($a,EXTR_OVERWRITE);// Please see manual to use `flags` accordingly
echo $name.'--'.$cuisine.'--'.$location.'--'.$price;
```

Working DEMO : https://3v4l.org/APqoE

Comment: I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306498/php-is-there-a-safe-way-to-extract-post) post is related to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your questions and example, I hope I get this right what you want.
You want a string for each form input that was recently posted by your user.

Your example:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){  
    $_SESSION['post'][$key]=$value; 
}
```

But from this you are not able to actually identify actual **index location** of the $key within the array location. Also it might contain all other key-values you do not need since you are capturing all the input. So why not do this instead?

```
if ($_POST['your-form']) {
    $array = [
       'name' => isset($_POST['name']) ? stripslashes($_POST['name']) : '',
       'cuisine' => isset($_POST['cuisine']) ? stripslashes($_POST['cuisine']) : '',
       'location' => isset($_POST['location']) ? stripslashes($_POST['location']) : '',
       'price' => isset($_POST['price']) ? stripslashes($_POST['price']) : '',   
    ];

    // now bind to session.
    $_SESSION['temp'] = $array;
}
```

Now, as for your string you need during the callback, simply:

```
list($name, $cuisine, $location, $price) = $_SESSION['temp'];

var_dump($name);
var_dump($cuisine);
var_dump($location);
var_dump($price);
```

---

Edit: based on comments.

We can do this.

```
function set_value($post_key) {
    $val = isset($_POST[$post_key])) ? stripslashes($_POST[$post_key]) : '';
    if (!empty($val)) {
       $_SESSION['temp'][$post_key] = $val; // store into session.
    }
}

function get_value($post_key) {
    return isset($_SESSION['temp'][$post_key]) ? $_SESSION['temp'][$post_key] : NULL;
}
```

So with both function, you can implement whenever you want. Here is a set.

```
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {
     set_value('cuisine'); // will store into session.
}
$cuisine = get_value('cuisine');
```