# How can I unset many values in array [php]

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an array of this form :

```
Array
(
    [1] => A
    [2] => B
    [3] => C
)
```

I want to delete values where key = 1 and 2...
I have tried this

```
unset($array['1']);
unset($array['2']);
```

But I need to call 2 times unset... It's possible without 2 calls ?

Thanks, have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

You can try like

```
$keyToRemove = array('1', '2');

foreach($keyToRemove as $key) {
   unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

Also you can do it like this way too

```
$arr = array_diff_key($arr, array_flip($keyToRemove));
```

Similar answer you can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884991/better-way-to-unset-multiple-array-elements)

Comment: *But I need to call 2 times unset... It's possible without 2 calls ?* this is still 2 calls of unset.