# Remove value from array - by value

Tags: php

I have an array of keys and values (words and their occurrences). I would like to remove certain keys (words). I have those words in another array. How do I filter out those word and create a new array?

I have tried this - but it doesn't remove the strings:

```
<?php
$words = array(
    'string 1' => 4,
    'string 2' => 6,
    'string 3' => 3,
    'string 4' => 3,
    'string 4' => 9,
    'string 5' => 8,
    'string 6' => 2,
    'string 7' => 10,
    'string 8' => 1
);

$remove_words = array(
    'string 4',
    'string 2'
);

$new_array = array_diff($words, $remove_words);

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

I would expect an output like this:

```
$new_array = array(
    'string 1' => 4,
    'string 3' => 3,
    'string 5' => 8,
    'string 6' => 2,
    'string 7' => 10,
    'string 8' => 1
);
```

Comment: Try unset($words[“string 1”]

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884991/better-way-to-unset-multiple-array-elements

Comment: array_diff_key()

Comment: Your array definition has repeated keys, these will clobber previously defined elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to change `$remove_words` values to keys, and then use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php). Try:

```
$new_array = array_diff_key($words, array_flip($remove_words));
```