# Can PHP's list() work with associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, list, associative-array

Example:

```
list($fruit1, $fruit2) = array('apples', 'oranges');
```

code above of course works ok, but code below:

```
list($fruit1, $fruit2) = array('fruit1' => 'apples', 'fruit2' => 'oranges');
```

gives: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in....`

Is there any way to refer to named keys somehow with list like `list('fruit1' : $fruit1)`, have you seen anything like this planned for future release?

Comment: Food for thought: [While destructuring an array, can the same element value be accessed more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807960/2943403)  ...and you can choose to omit elements during destructuring too.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**EDIT:** This approach was useful back in the day (it was asked & answered nine years ago), but see Kerem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253379/8112776) below for a better approach with newer PHP 7+ syntax.

Try the [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. It will create variables of all your keys, assigned to their associated values:

```
extract(array('fruit1' => 'apples', 'fruit2' => 'oranges'));
var_dump($fruit1);
var_dump($fruit2);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. On the other hand, it is almost always good practice to supply a prefix when using `extract` unless you are 100% absolutely certain which keys will be present.

Comment: Yes, I'd run it with array_intersect_key() first with expected keys.

Comment: But this won't work if you have an array like you get from `getimagesize()`.

Comment: @Jurik, true.  Using `list()` would be the way to go on `getimagesize()`

Comment: No, `list()` won't work either. Because the last two elements of this array have non numerical keys. I do not get it why they did such non sense with `getimagesize()`.

Comment: @Jurik, have you tried using `list()` with `array_values()`? You're right though--that function is weird.

Comment: Yeah, that is my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562608/how-to-convert-getimagesize-result-to-variables) too.

Comment: Please don't use `extract`. IDEs can't handle it. And it can create a [host of other problems.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/829454/178910)

Comment: my suggestion is to set variables in comment, so IDEs can read it, like
`extract(array('fruit1'=>'apples','fruit2'=>'oranges'));
/**
 * @var Array $fruit1
 * @var Array $fruit2
*/`

Comment: A very unreadable and bad solution! `list()` is much as readable as `extract` is.

Comment: see @K-Gun's answer for a PHP 7.1 solution. as peter mentioned, extract() is an old function that comes with a lot of problems, both subtle and catastrophic. the PHP doc page on extract() itself comes with a couple different warnings about its use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: I agree with peter, the only way for my IDE to know that the variables exist (and not mark them in red) is be declaring a /** @var $variableName **/ in front of the extract

Comment: PHP 7.1 offers a cleaner way - see K-Gun's answer instead.

Comment: @Bananaapple, I've edited my answer accordingly. I may be biased, but I'm not sure downvoting answers that were true at the time is necessarily the right approach. Thanks for calling it to my attention though.

Comment: I definitely see were you are coming from @landons but on the other hand it did have the desired effect - maybe something to enquire about on meta. In any case, thanks for the edit!

Comment: hmm... what if your array is like `array('omer@email.com'=>'Omer Aslam','landons@email.com'=>'Landons')` how are you going to access them ?

Answer (score 107):

With/from [PHP 7.1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax):

*For keyed arrays;*

```
$array = ['fruit1' => 'apple', 'fruit2' => 'orange'];

// [] style
['fruit1' => $fruit1, 'fruit2' => $fruit2] = $array;

// list() style
list('fruit1' => $fruit1, 'fruit2' => $fruit2) = $array;

echo $fruit1; // apple
```

*For unkeyed arrays;*

```
$array = ['apple', 'orange'];

// [] style
[$fruit1, $fruit2] = $array;

// list() style
list($fruit1, $fruit2) = $array;

echo $fruit1; // apple
```

Note: use `[]` style if possible by version, maybe [list](https://externals.io/message/109760) goes a new type in the future, who knows...

Answer (score 51):

What about using array_values()?

```
<?php
   list($fruit1, $fruit2) = array_values( array('fruit1'=>'apples','fruit2'=>'oranges') );
?>
```

Comment: This method is better (then accepted answer) if you want to skip some keys

Comment: This does not work if the values in the array are in reverse order, like `array('fruit2'=>'apples','fruit1'=>'oranges')`. The value of 'fruit2' is assigned $fruit1 and vice versa.

Comment: PHP 7.1 offers a cleaner way - see K-Gun's answer instead.

Comment: This works great for using older version of IDE such as PhpStorm 10.0.4 .

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to implement.

```
function orderedValuesArray(array &$associativeArray, array $keys, $missingKeyDefault = null)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($keys as &$key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $associativeArray)) {
            $result[] = $missingKeyDefault;
        } else {
            $result[] = $associativeArray[$key];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$arr = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
];
list($a, $b, $c) = orderedValuesArray($arr, ['a','AAA', 'c', 'b']);
echo $a, ', ', $b, ', ', $c, PHP_EOL;
```

output: `1, , 3`

- less typing on usage side
- no elements order dependency (unlike `array_values`)
- direct control over variables names (unlike `extract`) - smaller name collision risk, better IDE support

Comment: I see no benefit to making `$key` modifiable in the `foreach()` -- you never attempt to modify it.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I haven't programmed in PHP since 2017, but I think I did that to ensure `$key` isn't copied. Can't tell for sure at this point if that was my intention, or if that actually makes any technical difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in my case:

list() only works on numerical array. So if you can, leaving blank in fetch() or fetchAll() -> let it have 2 options: numerical array and associative array. It will work.

Answer (score -3):

consider this an elegant solution:

```
<?php

    $fruits = array('fruit1'=> 'apples','fruit2'=>'oranges');  

    foreach ($fruits as $key => $value)  
    {
        $$key = $value;  
    }
    echo $fruit1; //=apples  

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but in reality variable variables are almost never the "elegant" solution.

Comment: So why not using extract()? It basically does what you're solution is providing

Answer (score -5):

```
<?php

function array_list($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
}

$array = array('fruit2'=>'apples','fruit1'=>'oranges');

array_list($array);

echo $fruit1; // oranges


?>
```