# How to convert getimagesize() result to variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, getimagesize

Is there a function that gives me back all results of `getimagesize()` as associative array or single variables with self-explaining names? I know that I could do it with a foreach loop, but there must be a better way.

Result of `var_dump(getimagesize('foo.png'));`:

```
array
  0 => int 500
  1 => int 250
  2 => int 3
  3 => string 'width="500" height="250"' (length=24)
  'bits' => int 8
  'mime' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
```

### list()

Function [`list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) does not work because of its behavior:

> Note: list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical
>   indices start at 0.

### extract()

Function [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) could work if you use a prefix:

> Note that prefix is only required if flags is EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,
>   EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID or EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS. If the
>   prefixed result is not a valid variable name, it is not imported into
>   the symbol table. Prefixes are automatically separated from the array
>   key by an underscore character.

But then you would have variables like `<prefix>_0` and `<prefix>_1` and so on. That is not self-explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I found is to use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get a pure numerical indexed array and use it with [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

**Solution for single variables:**

```
list(
      $width, 
      $height, 
      $mimeType, 
      $htmlAttr, 
      $bits, 
      $mime
) = array_values(getimagesize('foo.png'));
```

**Solution for associative array:**

```
list(
     $imgInfo['width'], 
     $imgInfo['height'], 
     $imgInfo['mimeType'], 
     $imgInfo['htmlAttr'], 
     $imgInfo['bits'], 
     $imgInfo['mime']
) = array_values(getimagesize('foo.png'));
```