# list() function returns null php

Tags: php, list

I've tried to refactor my code by using the list() php function but it returns null and I am not sure what I am not doing well.
My code:

```
 public function test() {
      // content
      return ['variable' => $variable, 'variable1' => $variable1];
 }


 //
 list($variable, $variable1) = test();
```

I thought that's the way to use list().
Can someone give me a hint on what I am not doing alright?

Comment: no, the $variable is set in the `//content'. When I debug and I am at the return, the $variable and $variable1 are set. $variable is an array, and the other one is a string.

Comment: In provided code `$variable` is __never set__.

Comment: Dont add the keys. Let them be  ať offset 0 and 1.

Comment: Think https://stackoverflow.com/a/41253379/1213708 is the best answer from the duplicate (if your using PHP 7.1+)

Answer (score 1):

function `list()` is working for the numeric array only, in your case you should use [**extract()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function

```
 function test() {
  return ['variable' => 11, 'variable1' => 12];
 }
 extract(test());
 echo $variable.'--'.$variable1;
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/aVkpI