# PHP what does it mean when using this '$$var'?

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I am trying to learn php, and I saw this in a foreach loop what does it mean? 
I understand &$var which its a direct reference to the memory address of the object.
But what does $$var means? what is it exactly?

This is the example.

```
    foreach($this->vars as $key => $value)
    {
        $$key = $value;
        echo "$$Key: " . $$key;
        echo "Key: " . $key;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Value: " . $value;
    }
```

Comment: It is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: There are tutorials that cover this topic, this shouldn't be asked on SO, especially since the answer is available online from plenty of sources.

Comment: @downvoters Lay off the down votes, use your close votes, this is what they're for.

Comment: Use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=what+is+%24%24var+php) for such search queries.

Comment: Nothing to do with references.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Might help if you read that question :)

Comment: Ahh I get it thanks... although I couldn't FIND it in the internet, because I didnt know how to put the question in GOOGLE. Like "WHAT IS $$var in php"... didn't give me anything as actual answer, so thats why I aksed in SO.

The wierd thing about that code in a template is why would I have variable variables? what would they be used for? 
Well thanks anyways.

Comment: @Amal Murali: I did.  He said "I understand &$var. But what does $$var means?"  Not a reference that's for sure. :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver: *Please* read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) question. It's not about PHP reference. Reference as in mention/citiation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). e.g.

```
// original variable named 'foo'
$foo = "bar";

// reference $foo dynamically by evaluating $x
$x = "foo";
echo $$x; // "bar";
echo ${$x}; // "bar" as well but the {} allows you to perform concatenation

// different version of {} to show a more "complex" operation
$y = "fo";
$z = "o";
echo ${$y . $z}; // "bar" also ("fo" . "o" = "foo")
```

To show an example more closely matching your question:

```
$foo = "foo";
$bar = "bar";
$baz = "baz";

$ary = array('foo' => 'FOO','bar' => 'BAR','baz' => 'BAZ');
foreach ($ary as $key => $value){
  $$key = $value;
}

// end result is:
// $foo = "FOO";
// $bar = "BAR";
// $baz = "BAZ";
```

Comment: OMG this is perfect... so the idea is to create ACTUAL variables from the indexes of the array GOD DAM. thats an A+ HeadShot to the answer.

Comment: extract() does this without the loop and craziness.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: That's when you should read [why is it a bad idea to use `extract()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/) :)

Comment: lol good response. But i did look into thank you anyways @AbraCadaver

Comment: @Amal Murali: Blame the use not the tool.  I'm not a novice.  I state that it is roughly the same without the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable with the name `$key`. For example,
If `$k='somevar'`, then `$$k = $somevar`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable variable.  The var name is what is contained in `$var`.

If `$key = 'test'` then `$$key` will be evaluate to a var named `$test`.

Also, there are very few practical uses.  Most often arrays would be better.