# PHP extract values from an array and pass them to a function

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract values from an array, and pass them to a function where they'll be used. I've used `echo` inside the function for this example.

I'm using extract to get all the values.

Thing is, this wont work. Do you see how this can be done?

```
<?php

$my_array = array("a" => "Prince", "b" => "Funky"); // around 10 more

$g = extract($my_array);

foo($g);

function foo($g) {
    echo 'My name is '.$a.', and I am '.$b;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)?

Comment: @kingkero Actually, I'm trying it with what you suggested. How is it done? I keep getting some error or the other in spite of following the examples correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in PHP have a different scope, so the variables `$a`, `$b` etc. aren't available inside your function. Trying to use them inside the function would result in Undefined variable notices (if you [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393), that is).

Right now, you're storing the return value of `extract()` (which is the total number of variables parsed) into your function. You want the values instead, so change your function like so:

```
function foo($array) {
    extract($array);
    echo 'My name is '.$a.', and I am '.$b;
}
```

Note that I've moved the `extract()` call inside the function. This way, you wouldn't pollute the global scope with random variables (which may have undesired results and will make your debugging hard for no reason).

Now you can call your function, like so:

```
foo($my_array);
```

Output:

```
My name is Prince, and I am Funky
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/152422)

It's better to avoid `extract()` altogether, though. See: [What is so wrong with extract()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract)

Comment: And why to avoid extract?

Comment: the same arguments as for dont-ever-use-eval, especially with user input.

Comment: I really think that questions problem is with misunderstanding something or bad design, though.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass your array in your function as you do with any other variable

```
$my_array = array("a" => "Prince", "b" => "Funky"); // around 10 more

foo($my_array);

function foo($arrayData) 
{
    echo 'My name is '.$arrayData['a'].', and I am '.$arrayData['b'];
}
```