# How to array list unknown number of values

Tags: php

I want to do this:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = array('a', 'b', 'c');
my_function($a, $b, $c);
```

BUT with unknown number of values in the array

```
my_function(some_function($array));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think Machavity is right, but you can also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: duplicated call_user_func_array is the correct answer and aso the question is better explained than mine!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array to your function instead, this way you get all variables. If your array has keys, you can use the **[PHP extract() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)**.

```
// Build data array. Include keys as these will become the variable name later.
$data = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c');

// Call your function with data
my_function($data);

// Your function to parse data...
function my_function($data = NULL)
{
    // Verify you got data..
    if(is_null($data)){ return FALSE; }

    // Extract the array so that each value in the array gets assigned to a variable by it's key.
    extract($data);

    // Now you may echo values
    echo $a.$b.$c;
}
```

Another, more common option would be to loop through the array. Using a **[foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** you can reference each value of the array one at a time. This can be done like so:

```
// Build data array. Include keys as these will become the variable name later.
$data = array('a','b','c');

// Call your function with data
my_function($data);

// Your function to parse data...
function my_function($data = NULL)
{
    // Verify you got data..
    if(is_null($data)){ return FALSE; }

    // Loop through data to operate
    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        // Now you may echo values
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array as a parameter to a function, you may use a `foreach` loop to iterate through an array of any length.

```
someFunction($returnedArray){

 foreach($returnedArray as $value){
  echo $value
 }
}
```

The foreach will go element by element, assigning the current index's value to (in this case) $value.

Answer (score -3):

Just don't use `list()`  function.

Pass an array to function. `my_function(array(a,  b,  c,...))`. It will be better if you will use hash array. Also `extract()`  is not a good idea.

See: [this blog](http://php.dzone.com/news/php-bad-practice-use-extract) and [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/829454/1909755)

Comment: I downvoted this so I feel obligated to say why. Just saying that extract() is not a good idea gives users that search and find this thread no explanation behind why they should not use it. Instead, consider explaining the risks of extract() and/or not providing the same answer as others.

Comment: 1. http://php.dzone.com/news/php-bad-practice-use-extract
2. http://stackoverflow.com/a/829454/1909755
Is it ok?