# How to use extract() to get the values of a form?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm just learning PHP and I'm following a tutorial. Now I'm on the part where we examine server-side form validation and the tutorial uses the `request_import_variables` to get the values and validate them. But this method is deprecated now. How can I get the values from a form that are stored in an array? I tried using extract but I'm not that familiar with the syntax and I don't get the result that I want. Here is the code.

```
<?php
//In this example I'm going to get the values of the form 
//and validate them on the server.
if(isset($_POST['Form'])) {
    //import_request_variables isn't supported anymore by php
    //import_request_variables("p", "z");
    extract($_POST['Form'], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "z");
    $missingFields = array();
    $required = array("FName"=>"First Name", "LName"=>"Last Name");

    while(list($var, $val) = each($required)){
        if(isset($zForm[$var]) && $zForm[$var] != ''){
            if(is_string($zForm[$var]))
                print "Everything ok <br />";
            else
                print "You have to provide a valid first and last name <br />";
        }
        else {
            $missingFields[$var] = $val;
        }
    }

    if(count($missingFields)){
        print "You missed out one or more fields:<br />";

        while(list($var, $val) = each($missingFields)){
            print $val . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        print "Form passed!<br />";
        var_dump($zForm['Languages']);
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="formValidation.php">
First Name: <input type="text" name="Form[FName]" /> (required)<br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="Form[LName]" /> (required) <br />
Age: <input type="text" name="Form[Age]" /><br /><br />
Languages known:<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Form[Languages][]" value="PHP" checked="checked"> PHP</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="Form[Languages][]" value="CPP"> C++</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="Form[Languages][]" value="Delphi"> Delphi</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="Form[Languages][]" value="Java"> Java</input>
<input type="submit" />
```

As a result I get `You missed one or more fields 
First Name 
Last Name`

[Here is the section of the tutorial I'm stuck](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/7/7/3/validation-in-practice)

Comment: There's no need to extract it in the first place. You can just localize the input array per `$form = $_REQUEST["Form"];` to access fields more conveniently. (Nothing wrong with `extract()` per se. But you really should avoid it in the global scope - which is what this excerpt looks like.)

Comment: It kind of worked with the tip that you gave me. But when I put a number as a name the form still passes. Do the values get converted to strings and put in the array? For example I can put 1234 as a name and I will get the result "Form passed"

Comment: You are making an assignment in each of your while loops (`list($var, $val) = each($required)`) which should be `list($var, $val) == each($required)`.

Comment: No it should be `=` because that is how you traverse a list with each. If you put `==` you get an error.

Comment: @captain Yes. All request vars will come across as strings or arrays of strings/arrays (if they are nested or you have multiple input elements with the same `name` attribute). For numbers you can use `is_numeric` or `ctype_digit` to check that the value is numeric, then if you need to be really strict you can cast it to the numeric type you are expecting and validate it against more specific rules. Or you could just convert it and then check that. Depends on what you are trying to validate.

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid extracting variables!** Instead of this you should work with array directly. Discussion about this bad `extract` practice is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract).

---

As for your, code, you made a little mistake here:

```
extract($_POST['Form'], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "z");
```

This `extract` will make variables from `$_POST['Form']` array, such as `$z_FName`, `$z_LName`, `$z_Age`, etc.

The code from tutorial:

```
import_request_variables("p", "z");
```

This `import_request_variables` will make variables from `$_POST` array, so it will be just `$z_Form`.

So you need change

`extract($_POST['Form'], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "z");`

to

`extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "z");`

And change `$zForm` to `$z_Form`.

If you'll debug such cases, you may have a look to a `get_defined_vars` function.

Comment: I would move the warning about extract to the beginning of your answer, and bold it. Then follow up.