# Using parameters in Associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use 
`$array['parameter']` where parameter is taken from post array or is set previously, though php won't allow that?
Why it can't be used like in string statements

```
$string = "This is my parameter $parameter";
```

Comment: Could you show some more of your actual code? Not quite sure what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'parameter' is a key in your post array, you can access it with:

```
$_POST['parameter']
```

Thus, you can do:

```
$parameter = $_POST['parameter'];
$string = "This is my parameter $parameter";
```

Or, just for your own edification, you can extract all (key, value) pairs of an array into variables.  Since  $_POST is an array, you can use the extract() function on it.  However, using extract() comes with inherent risks.  If you choose to go this route, be sure you have a *great* reason for using extract() -- odds are, any reason you can think of isn't *great* enough (Further reading: [What is so wrong with extract()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract)).

```
//We expect 'parameter' to be a key in the $_POST array.
extract($_POST);
if(isset($parameter)) {
    $string = "This is my parameter $parameter";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

As always, be sure to sanitize your input: [The ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)

Comment: @Terminus, I debated adding that snippet, as well.  I erred on the side of "more knowledge is better" but perhaps I should have added a disclaimer.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

to use $array['parameter'] where parameter is taken from post array or is set previously, though php won't allow that? Why it can't be used like in string statements

So I'll take a stab at this since you've added some code.
If you want to access an element in an array based on the value of a variable you simply

```
$array[$value]
```

If you want to use a value held by the `$_POST` array to act as the key you

```
$array[$_POST['parameter']]
```

If you only want to do that if the value is set in `$_POST`

```
if (isset($_POST['parameter']))
  // use the value here as before
```

Now, if you just want to stick a value from an array into a string without using the `.` concatenation operator, wrap it in curly braces like so:

```
$string = "This is my parameter {$array['parameter']}
```

Be careful when using user input for anything. @Tim had a link to a good answer on that: [sanitize input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)