# Using array as function parameter, and extracting it as variables

Tags: php

I'm making function to insert some data into my database:

```
function updateInfo($company, $address, $postalnumber, $city, $phone, $email, $ip, $officehours, $etc){}
```

...and figured out i needed to set most of the parameters optional:

```
function updateInfo($company=NULL, $address=NULL, $postalnumber=NULL, $city=NULL, $phone=NULL, $email=NULL, $ip=NULL, $officehours=NULL, $etc=NULL){}
```

..until i figured out the parameter list became too long. So i discovered `extract()` and made my parameter list an array of optionals instead:

```
function updateInfo($vars){
    extract($vars);
}
```

Would you use `extract()` this way, or is there better way to pass a lot of optional variables into a function?

Comment: There are two questions here and both are off-topic as they are too broad

Comment: I will try to narrow it

Comment: If a parameter list is becoming too long, it's generally a sign that you need more than one function, not that you need to consolidate the parameters into an array

Comment: extract is a good way but a little too magic for me because you can be disappointed when you see variables that have not been defined anywhere.  I would suggest to just access the variable like this : $array['var'] when you have to use it.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at something like a [builder pattern](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the use of **extract()** too magic because we don't know from where  variables are coming as they are not defined anywhere.

You must consider to use the array as it:

```
$array['key'];
```

or

```
$key = $array['key'];
```

This is not so bad, and it's **very clear for everyone who will read your code**.

And i'm okay with the use of an array instead of a lot of parameters where some are optionals.
Wordpress is working this way.

For example it has a function that allow you to get posts with some arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 'status
);

$pages = get_posts($args);
```

And there is a lot of other arguments that are optionals that **make it easy** the use of the function.

You can think of adding an `$default array()` in your function with all the default arguments and **merge it with the array given in parameters**.

Please see this thread as a reference of it : 
[What is so wrong with extract()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use an array because the possible fields that can be modified are so large, then I suggest you refactor your code to inherently work with the array. Here is an example that builds an SQL query as well as modifies an internal state array (yes, it's a contrived example):

```
<?php

function updateInfo($fields) {
        static $state = [
                'company' => 'oldCompany',
                'address' => 'oldAddress'
        ];
        $setList = [];
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                echo("Changing field " . $key . " from " . $state[$key] . " to " . $value . "\n");
                $state[$key] = $value;
                array_push($setList, $key . " = \"" . $value . "\""); // TODO escape SQL properly
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE myTable SET " . join(", ", $setList) . " WHERE myRowId = 123456";
        echo($sql . "\n");
}

updateInfo([
        'company' => 'newCompany',
        'address' => 'newAddress'
]);

?>
```

You can test the above code by saving it to a file such as `example.php` file and running `php example.php` in a console.

NOTE: you could instead of blindly accepting the keys from the input array, you could examine the key with a switch statement inside of the foreach loop and have more advanced specialized logic per key type.

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through an associated array and assign variables that way based on the key:

```
$values = array(
    'foo'=>'John',
    'bar'=>'Smith'
);

foreach($values as $variable=>$value){
    $$variable = $value;
}

echo $foo;
echo $bar;
// echos JohnSmith
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of good suggestions, I'm figuring out that actually **using** the array can be beneficial. So I'm considering this:

```
updateInfo($vars) { 
    foreach($vars as $key->value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'phonenumber':
                ...
                break;
            case 'etc':
                ...
                break;
            default:
                ...
         }
     }
}
```

It leaves me with unlimited arguments, even without knowing about them (`default:`) as well as the possibility to be specific with ´case 'specific':`