# Html form failing to pass data to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

After connecting my Html form to MySQL database, but I kept getting an error when I hit the submit button, No data was passed to the database.

**Below is a screenshot of the error I got.**

[image: Error message]

Create database and Table structure

```
 // create a database  
//CREATE DATABASE student
//USE student

// create a table studentdetails   
//CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studentdetails 

(
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name char(50) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  mobile bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  gender enum('m','f') NOT NULL,
  hobbies varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  dob date NOT NULL,
  address text NOT NULL,
  profilePic varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  registrationDate datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY email (email)
)
```

PHP Scripts Connect to MySQL Database and get the value from HTML Form

**connect.php** code

```
<?php
//connectivity
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("not connected");
//select database
mysql_select_db("student",$con);

extract($_POST);
if(isset($save))
{
//for date of birt get one by one and concatente
$dob=$yy."-".$mm."--".$dd;
//hobbies retrieve in an array format change array into string 
$h=implode(",",$hobb);
$img=$_FILES['pic']['name'];

//To check user already exists or not
$sql=mysql_query("select email from studentdetails where email='$e'");
$return=mysql_num_rows($sql);
//if $return returns true value it means user's email already exists
if($return)
{
$msg="<font color='red'>".ucfirst($e)."already exists choose another email</font>";
}
else
{
$query="insert into studentdetails values('','$n','$e','$p','$m','$g','$h','$dob','$add','$img',now())";
mysql_query($query);
$msg= "<font color='blue'>Your data saved</font>";
}
}
?>
```

//HTML Script Registration form

**Register.html** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Registration Form</title>
<style>
input,textarea{width:200px}
input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox]{width:10px}
input[type=submit],input[type=reset]{width:100px}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="393" border="1">
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo @$msg; ?></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="159">Enter your Name</td>
    <td width="218">
    <input type="text" placeholder="your first name"  name="n" pattern="[a-z A-Z]*" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your Email</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="e"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="p"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your Address</td>
    <td><textarea name="add"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your Mobile</td>
    <td><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="m" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="23">Select your Gender</td>
    <td>
    Male<input type="radio" name="g" value="m"/>
    Female<input type="radio" name="g" value="f"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choose your Hobbies</td>
    <td>
        Cricket<input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="hobb[]"/>
        Singing<input type="checkbox" value="singing" name="hobb[]"/>
        Dancing<input type="checkbox" value="dancing" name="hobb[]"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Choose your Profile Pic </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="pic"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Select your DOB</td>
    <td>
        <select name="mm">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
            {
            echo "<option value='$i'>".$i."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select name="dd">
            <option value="">Date</option>
            <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
            {
            echo "<option value='$i'>".$i."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select name="yy">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <?php 
            for($i=1900;$i<=2015;$i++)
            {
            echo "<option value='$i'>".$i."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Register Me"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot of the error message I got**

Comment: Note that mysql_* extension has been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. You should consider switching to mysqli or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo) (recommended).

Comment: Besides what @El_Vanja you are wide open to SQL injection if you simply convert to mysqli functions. As they suggest use PDO and you need to use prepared statements. Also [don't use extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829407/what-is-so-wrong-with-extract).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Fatal error : Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441178/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Comment: **Never `extract($_POST);`** This is really dangarous.

Answer (score -1):

try this:
In the php code:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student");
```

also:
change mysql_query to mysqli_query

In the html code:

```
  <form method="POST" action="nameOfthePhpFile.php">
```